# Bug: "No eligible question found at that url." for close as duplicate of Meta.SO question

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

Inquiring about [Which rich text editor it is used on SE? Is that under free licence?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15065/which-rich-text-editor-it-is-used-on-se-is-that-under-free-licence#question) question here on Pro Webmasters.

Close dialog returns "No eligible question found at that url." when attempting to close as duplicate of [What HTML editor is used by Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/what-html-editor-is-used-by-stack-overflow)

Question left open for repro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only close a question as a duplicate of a question on the *same site*.

Closing as duplicate of a question on *another site in the network* is not supported.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion on my end. Could the close dialog message be updated to check against the site and advise of this limitation when a close attempt is made against another SE site's question?

Comment: @danle good idea, I'll try to get that added